# What is the purpose of uItem parameter in InsertMenuItem()?

Tags: c++, winapi

This is what InsertMenuItem() documentation say:

```
uItem [in]

    Type: UINT

    The identifier or position of the menu item before which to insert the new item. The meaning of this parameter depends on the value of fByPosition.
```

But then what is the purpose of MENUITEMINFO.wID?

```
wID

    Type: UINT

    An application-defined value that identifies the menu item. Set fMask to MIIM_ID to use wID.
```

Note that I tested both parameters, and only wID worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But then what is the purpose of MENUITEMINFO.wID?

`uItem` controls the location *where the new menu item is inserted*.  `wID` controls the *ID of the new menu item*.

Suppose you have a menu with 3 items in it with identifiers `IDM_FOO`, `IDM_BAR`, and `IDM_BAZ`.  Now suppose you want to insert a 4th item with identifier `IDM_QUUX` into the menu between the `IDM_FOO` and `IDM_BAR` items.  You can do that by using `InsertMenuItem()` to insert it either before `IDM_BAR` (using `fByPosition == FALSE`) or before index 1 (using `fByPosition == TRUE`).  For example:

```
MENUITEMINFO mii;
ZeroMemory(&mii, sizeof(mii));
mii.cbSize = sizeof(mii);
mii.fMask = MIIM_ID | /* Other flags */;
mii.wID = IDM_QUUX;  // ID of new menu item to be inserted
// Fill out other fields
... 
// Insert new menu item before the IDM_BAR item
InsertMenuItem(hMenuParent, IDM_BAR, FALSE, &mii);
...
// OR, insert new menu item before position 1
InsertMenuItem(hMenuParent, 1, TRUE, &mii);
```

As for this comment:

> Note that I tested both parameters, and only wID worked!

You'll have to clarify what you mean by "only wID worked."  Worked how so?  What exactly did you do, what happened, and what did you expect to happen?  Make sure you read the documentation carefully to understand how the functions and structures are intended to work.

Comment: I thought that they meant by changing the fByPosition value to FALSE then uItem would be interpreted as the ID of the menu item that I'm creating!! What I meant by "wID worked" is that by setting MENUITEMINFO.wID I was able to receive a WM_COMMAND message.